# Can you switch .net frameworks quickly?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I've only ever used .net 3.5 framework but am looking into getting 4 or possibly 4.5 however if 4/4.5 don't work with the rest of the application I'm working on, is there a quicky way to switch between the two frameworks rather than having to reinstall the the 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET binaries *target* a certain version of the .NET framework, they don't just use whatever the latest is on the machine.  Thus, when you switch from the 3.5 to 4.0 framework, you'd have to re-compile your app targeting that new framework version.  This can be done in Visual Studio within the project options here:

[image]

If you wanted to switch back, you'd just switch the target back and recompile again.  Provided you didn't uninstall the older version of the framework or anything.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a matter of (un)installation, only a matter of choosing the Target Framework of your projects (under the project settings -> Target framework, choose .NET Framework 4 or 3.5 accordingly)